# Change putty translation to UTF-8 by remote machine

Tags: unix, terminal, putty

How to change "**remote character set**" in Translation of a putty by remote machine?

Its by default set to ISO, so when I run my application, I get weird characters. It can be changed by host machine.

But can I change the putty terminal settings from remote machine via some command so that I can ensure that I always get desired characters?

Answer (score 1):

I fear it is not possible. character set is controlled by LC_* environment variables. Putty has no way to get theirs values.

You can associate "remote character set" with each account in Putty. It should be sufficient.

The best thing is to configure all your environments in UTF-8 (which is default for all major systems).